# onkeyup not working when onchange did php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have both onkeyup and onchange function in the same page. When onchange function did an action onkeyup function did not responding anything. But When I did not make any action to onchange function, onkeyup function responds very good.

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkname()

{



var name=document.getElementById( "UserName" ).value;

 if(name)
 {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'process/cr_checkdata.php',
  data: {
   user_name:name,
  },



success: function (response) {
   $( '#name_status' ).html(response);
   if(response=="OK")   
   {
    return true;    
   }
   else
   {
    return false;   
   }
  }
  });
 }
 else
 {
  $( '#name_status' ).html("");
  return false;
 }
}
function getSubtitle(val) {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "cr_case.php",
data:'title='+val,
success: function(data){
    $("#subtitle-list").html(data);
}
});
}

function showMsg()

{

$("#msgC").html($("#title-list option:selected").text());
$("#msgS").html($("#subtitle-list option:selected").text());
return false;
}

</script>
```

How can I solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the code inside functions. It has to do with reserved words. You can not use JavaScript reserved words as the name of the function or variable.

I found `onkeyup` in the list of JavaScript reserved words in the link below. But you also should not use `onchange` as it is used in the change event handling which is common in JavaScript. You can not use one of those reserved words as the name of your function or variable.

Make sure that the names of your function or variable are unique so that they can not conflict with the JavaScript's own keywords.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp